# Working with OpenId protocol

Tags: c#, openid, openid-connect

I am having some trouble authenticating with OpenId Connect.
I set breakpoints in the events for the OpenId and after the authentication process I am only getting a MessageReceived (at least I am receiving the token…) and consequently I am not successful authenticated! I think I should be receiving the access token in the AuthorizationCodeReceived.

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;

                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(
                                    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                                code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                            token = result.AccessToken;

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                        {
                            //context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                            //context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        MessageReceived = (context) =>
                        {                            
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        SecurityTokenReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                        {
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Any idea about why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: I realize this is nearly 6 years old, but did you ever figure out why? I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related with the Katana library (MS owin). It is necessary to override the CookieManager class in order to force OWIN to use the .NET cookie.

```
public class SystemWebCookieManager : ICookieManager
{
    public string GetRequestCookie(IOwinContext context, string key)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }

        var webContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);
        var cookie = webContext.Request.Cookies[key];
        return cookie == null ? null : cookie.Value;
    }

    public void AppendResponseCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, string value, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
        }

        var webContext = context.Get<HttpContextBase>(typeof(HttpContextBase).FullName);

        bool domainHasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Domain);
        bool pathHasValue = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.Path);
        bool expiresHasValue = options.Expires.HasValue;

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(key, value);
        if (domainHasValue)
        {
            cookie.Domain = options.Domain;
        }
        if (pathHasValue)
        {
            cookie.Path = options.Path;
        }
        if (expiresHasValue)
        {
            cookie.Expires = options.Expires.Value;
        }
        if (options.Secure)
        {
            cookie.Secure = true;
        }
        if (options.HttpOnly)
        {
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        }

        webContext.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
    }

    public void DeleteCookie(IOwinContext context, string key, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (options == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("options");
        }

        AppendResponseCookie(
            context,
            key,
            string.Empty,
            new CookieOptions
            {
                Path = options.Path,
                Domain = options.Domain,
                Expires = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
            });
    }
}
```

And then in the startup class:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    ...
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
    ...
});
```